# How long does cheese last out of the refrigerator

Tags: cheese, spoilage

We went on vacation and while we were gone, the refrigerator in which I stored a GREAT DEAL of cheese (both hard and soft, although unopened) quit working and when we returned home, I found the cheese defrosted (I had put it in the freezer).  Is it safe to transfer to my other refrigerator?  The packages are unopened and there is no indication of spoilage.

Answer (score 0):

At what temperature was the freezer when you discovered the problem?  If it was below 40 F / 4 C, the cheese remained at refrigerator temperatures....  if it was warmer, you have no way of knowing for how long, and should discard the cheese.

Comment: Actually, I would keep the cheeses which are designed to last in cellars for a long time. They are safe even at room temp, just unappetizing because of melted fat. But anything semi-hard (young gouda/emmentaller/cheddar) and softer is certainly a loss.